# vb.net For Each block has an extra run (run twice)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, loops, foreach, datatable

I have a datatable and I want to convert one row to a single string with all the column names, so the format will be like: 
column1_name: column1_content. column2_name: column2_content...

I almost got it done the way I wanted, except that the result will be the same string repeated twice. For example, a string "abc" is what I want, but it will return "abcabc".

It's ok when I had only 1 row, I could use exit keyword to terminate the loop after 1 run, but now I have datatables with more than 1 row, which was unexpected, so the loop has to finish. Please help me find out the reason. Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
    Dim column As New DataColumn
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Load(dr)

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each column In dt.Columns
            If Not IsDBNull(row.ItemArray.GetValue(i)) Then
                sData = sData & column.ColumnName & ": " & row.ItemArray.GetValue(i).ToString & ". " & vbLf
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: I used your code in a simple test and could not reproduce the problem. Try handcrafting some some sample data to see if the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'set up dummy data
Dim dtb As New DataTable
dtb.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Col0", GetType(String)))
dtb.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Col1", GetType(String)))
dtb.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Col2", GetType(String)))
dtb.Rows.Add("R0C0", "R0C1", "R0C2")
dtb.Rows.Add("R1C0", "R1C1", "R1C2")
'extract rows
Dim sbl As New System.Text.StringBuilder
For intRow As Integer = 0 To dtb.Rows.Count - 1
  Dim drw As DataRow = dtb.Rows(intRow)
  For intCol As Integer = 0 To dtb.Columns.Count - 1
    If drw.Item(intCol) IsNot Nothing Then
      sbl.AppendLine("Row " & intRow.ToString & " " & dtb.Columns(intCol).ColumnName & ": " & drw.Item(intCol).ToString & ". ")
    End If
  Next intCol
Next intRow
MsgBox(sbl.ToString)
dtb.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks, after re-testing my own code it seems everything works, and I haven't modified anything. I have no idea why it gave me "doubled" result yesterday. I don't have the reputation to thumb up your reply yet, but I really appreciate it.